# Configure output dir for Assetic in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, assetic

I'd like to globally configure the output dir of where assetic dumps my JS files. Currently, they always go to `web/js/*`. I want to change this to `web/js/compiled/*`.

It's possible to specify this at a per-file level: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files

Can't seem to find a way to set this globally across my Symfony app. Any config parameter I'm missing?

**UPDATE**

Found an assetic config parameter called `write_to`. Setting this in `config.yml` causes the command line `assetic:dump` to dump files to the new dir, but within twig files the `asset_url` var still points to the original path.

Comment: did you ever come up with a solution?  I would have assumed that the `read_from` option in the config would be what we're looking.  However, I can't get that option to do anything. Regardless of what I set the read_from parameter to, my application uses the default path.

Comment: @kmfk Nothing yet. Right now, we're just setting the `output` param for each `javascripts` block, but that's not at all ideal.

Comment: Yeah, I have assetic dump my assets straight to our S3 bucket and I wanted the prod environment to read files from there - while the dev environment dumps to a local folder and like-wise, my templates should read from that folder while on our dev server.  I ended up checking the environment in the controller and passing a var to the template to prefix the `asset_url` for the cdn.  Not ideal, but it does the job.

Comment: So why exists this "write_to" parameter, when the variable {{ asset_url }} does not heed to it. That is not thought through at all... :(

Answer (score 17):

You should use the property **write_to**.

in my configuration for exemple I use

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: %kernel.debug%
    read_from:      %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/views/
    write_to:       %kernel.root_dir%/../web/static/
```

Your *ouput* string start where ends *write_to*

for exemple

```
{% javascripts filter="closure" output='js/main.js'
```

...

```
 {% stylesheets filter='compass,?cssrewrite' 
     'default/static/sass/screen.scss' 
     output='css/screen.css' 
 %}
```

both will placed respectively in ***/web/static/js/main.js***
and ***/web/static/css/screen.css***

[**assets_base_urls**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#assets-base-urls) is used to specify base URL's to be used for assets referenced from http and ssl (https) pages.

**!!** `assets_base_urls` is also used by `{% images %}` as the root before `output` value, but `{% images %}` doesn't consider `write_to` when rendering html (only when dumping) so better not using `write_to` and rely only on `output` value. **More about it in [my other post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225000/static-asset-dumping-with-png-optimization-references-wrong-files) and in [this post on AsseticBundle's github](https://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle/issues/186)**.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the asset path ( `assets_base_urls` ) for twig to a static path, instead of using the relative path.  In your config.yml file, it would look similar to this:

```
framework:
   templating:
      engines: ['twig']
         assets_base_urls:
            http: [http://path.to-cdn.com]
```

This will effect `asset_url` from assetic as well as twig's `asset()` method.  The latter may or may not be desired.

Answer (score 2):

[This GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle/issues/186#issuecomment-16026271) helped me with this issue.
While in dev, your assets will still go thru the controller but in production, the URLs will be as you desire.

Example config.yml:

```
assetic:
    write-to:  %kernel.root_dir%/../web/assets
    ...
framework:
    ...
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        packages:
            assetic:
                base_urls: '/assets'
```

Example in your template:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {% javascripts '@jquery' '@bootstrap_js' '@backbone' '@handlebars' combine=true package='assetic' %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

Notice that you have to add the package='assetic' attribute in the java scripts tag. This is a good compromise IMO because it won't break assets from other bundles as kmfk's solution will.

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick note on this. If you're using `assets_base_urls`, to specify a relative base URL, this only works prior to Symfony 2.7, due to the introduction of the new assets component in that version. Further information on how to change this is available at http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-the-new-asset-component , but the long and short of it is that:

```
framework:
    templating:
        assets_base_urls: 
            http: ['/some-relative-url']
            ssl: ['/some-relative-url']
```

becomes:

```
framework:
    assets:
        base_path: /some-relative-url
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this commande `$ app/console --env=prod assetic:dump web/`
you have juste to change the url you want raher than 'web/'