# Assetic creates wrong path in template

Tags: symfony, assetic

Im am using Symfony 2.5.3 with Assetic Bundle 2.5.0. Assetic keeps generating wrong urls to generated asset files.

My config_dev.yml looks like this:

```
assetic:
    use_controller: false
    write_to: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/dev/dev-env/
```

When I run `php app/console assetic:dump --env=dev` the files are correctly written to the above configured directory.

However, in the twig template, the output is like this:

```
<script src="/js/7cca762_part_4_timer_2-33c923b.js"></script>
<script src="/js/7cca762_part_4_uploader_3-6336104.js"></script>
```

when it should be

```
<script src="/dev/dev-env/js/7cca762_part_4_timer_2-33c923b.js"></script>
<script src="/dev/dev-env/js/7cca762_part_4_uploader_3-6336104.js"></script>
```

The twig template looks like this:

```
{% javascripts
    '@AcmeProjectBundle/Resources/js/*' filter='?uglifyjs2'
%}
<script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Any ideas?

**Update:**
I just found [this Stackoverflow item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412944/configure-output-dir-for-assetic-in-symfony2) describing the same problem - also without a clear solution so far.

Comment: There is also a "read_from" config parameter: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/assetic.html I didn't try, but maybe this is where the path for the templates comes from.

Comment: I did try. Seems not to work.

Answer (score 0):

try out asset base urls

```
framework:
    templating:      
        assets_base_urls:
            http: your.url.com/dev/dev-env
```

Comment: This works partly: The assets now come from the correct folder, however assets which are loaded directly (e.q. images) also get this prefix.